# Android Camera2 Parameters Flatten

Tags: java, android, android-camera

Is there anything similar to Camera Parameters [flatten](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#flatten()) but for the camera2 API? I saw a [WritetoParcel](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#writeToParcel(android.os.Parcel,%20int)) on CaptureRequest but cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with the former API's flatten method, but I have been working with the camera2 API and needed a similar thing. Specifically, I wanted human-readable versions of the parameters contained in various forms of CameraMetadata. I ended up hard-coding something myself, which may help you.

Here is my [CameraReport utility class](https://github.com/rcsumner/devCam/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/devcam/CameraReport.java).

If contains a function to turn, e.g., CaptureRequest key values into their labels, and a function that does this to turn an entire CaptureRequest object into a JSON file.

You could easily repurpose the relevant code from writeCaptureRquestToFile() to output to another string instead of a file, which I think might be what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the source code. I am doing the same thing currently (using getKeys) but I'm looking for a similar way just like the old camera flatten and unflatten. If I get nothing in a couple days I'll mark this as correct as it does work.